# Using AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate without a preview window

Tags: swift, macos, avfoundation, avcapturesession, cmsamplebuffer

I'm working on a Swift-based macOS app where I need to capture video input, but not display it on the screen...rather than display the video, I want to send the buffered data for processing elsewhere, and eventually display it on an object in a `SceneKit` scene.

I have a `CameraInput` class that has a `prepareCamera` method:

```
    fileprivate func prepareCamera() {
        self.videoSession = AVCaptureSession()
        self.videoSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo

        if let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices() as? [AVCaptureDevice] {
            for device in devices {
                if device.hasMediaType(AVMediaType.video) {
                    cameraDevice = device

                    if cameraDevice != nil  {
                        do {
                            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: cameraDevice)


                            if videoSession.canAddInput(input) {
                                videoSession.addInput(input)
                            }


                           } catch {
                            print(error.localizedDescription)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            let videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
            videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self as AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate, queue: DispatchQueue(label: "sample buffer delegate", attributes: []))
            if videoSession.canAddOutput(videoOutput) {
                videoSession.addOutput(videoOutput)
            }
        }
    }
```

And a `startSession` method that starts the `AVCaptureSession` session:

```
fileprivate func startSession() {
    if let videoSession = videoSession {
        if !videoSession.isRunning {
            self.videoInputRunning = true
            videoSession.startRunning()
        }
    }
}
```

I also implement `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate`, where I intend to capture the `CMSampleBuffer` for later use:

```
extension CameraInput: AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {

    internal func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
        print(Date())
    }
}
```

However, the delegate is never called. Is this a situation where I *have* to display the video output in order for this to be called?

Comment: Under what class are you writing these lines of code?  And what is your input device?

Comment: @ElTomato the input device is just my mac's iSIght camera. The class is a custom class called CameraInput that inherits from NSObject.

Comment: You are not using previewLayer.  What is it for?  To my knowledge, you do need it.

Comment: @ElTomato Agh, yes; that was left in there by accident - I updated my code above.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

None of your issues have to do with whether (or not) you display a preview of captured video.

If you're on Swift 4 (and it looks like you are), the delegate method signature you're looking to implement isn't `captureOutput(_:didOutputSampleBuffer:from:)`, it's [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturevideodataoutputsamplebufferdelegate/1385775-captureoutput):

```
optional func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, 
              didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, 
                     from connection: AVCaptureConnection)
```

---

Unrelated tips:

- Namespaced constants mean you can be more brief if you like; e.g. `videoSession.sessionPreset = .photo`
- `AVCaptureDevice.devices()` is deprecated. Instead of calling that and looping through devices yourself, just [ask `AVCaptureDevice` for exactly the kind of device you want](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/2361508-default):

  ```
  let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, 
                                         for: .video, position: .back)
  ```
- You don't need the `as` cast in `videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self as AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate` if your class already declares conformance to the `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate` protocol.

---

Finally, if you're just looking to get the live-from-camera video mapped onto some part of a SceneKit scene, note that in iOS 11 you can assign an `AVCaptureDevice` to an `SCNMaterialProperty`'s `contents` directly — no need to grab, process, and move pixel buffers yourself.

Comment: Great answer and these tips are useful! thanks.

Comment: Wow, I really wish SpriteKit had that same `contents` feature. I'm trying to show a webcam in a SKNode, and it's looking like I have to copy each frame into a texture.